# alternative to .append() for increasing performance in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day all, I'm trying to make a shooting game using jQuery where bullets are generated as a `div` and I'm using `.append()` to generate the bullets. Bullets are generating perfectly but the problem is when a bunch of them loads, performance gets slower. After googling I found that it's happening because of `.append()` But I can't figure out how to change my code.
Here are my codes:

```
function spawnBullet(canvasid, objectid, bulletid, bulletclass, left, top) {
 var canvasID = $('#' + canvasid);
 var objectID = $('#' + objectid);
 var bulletID = bulletid;
 var bulletClass = bulletclass;
 var adjust_left = left;
 var adjust_top = top;
 var objectLeft = objectID.offset().left - adjust_left;
 var objectTop = objectID.offset().top - adjust_top;
 var appendingValue = "<div class="+bulletClass+" id="+bulletID+" style='left: "+objectLeft+"; top: "+objectTop+";'></div>";
 $("#content").append(appendingValue);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this problem? I desperately need this help. Tnx.

Comment: jQuery is a cross browser `DOM` manipulation library ... If you want gaming-sort-of-performance, then avoid using jquery all together; use native js or some other libraries...

Comment: @TJ, yes I also found that native JS is fastest. But I can't figure it out how to use that in here since I've been practicing jQuery a lot and totally forgot JS. Can u give me example by code?

Comment: [this](http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/) will probably help you. Compare jquery with the other libraries.

Comment: BTW it looks like you're using `<canvas>`, why aren't you drawing bullets on canvas rather than appending `<div>`'s to `DOM`? `DOM` manipulation is too costly in terms of performance...

Comment: @TJ, I'm not using canvas. I just gave a div's id canvas. I used DOM jquery because novice like me find very easy to learn and code, plus I found jquery collision plugin which is awesome. To be honest I'm not comfortable with JS-Canvas elements.

Comment: it would be a lot quicker to make one bullet at the start, use elm.cloneNode(true), adjust the attribs, and append that instead of the string.